# How to bind a TextBox on the MainWindow to the DataGrid on UserControl?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, user-controls

I have TextBox and UserControl on MainWindow. UserControl contain DataGrid. I use next binding:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxOnMainWindow" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControlWithGrid, Path=GridOnMyUserControl.SelectedItem.name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200"/>
```

It does not work. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using MVVM? Either use dependency property or data binding to achieve what you need. You cannot access a datagrid in a user control simply. Maybe if you have a dependency property, just refer to it.

Comment: I don't use MVVM. Can I do it without MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just access the data grid of your UserControl. You can easily proxy the selected item from your DataGrid:

```
/// <summary>
///     Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class UserControl1
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDataGridItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedDataGridItem", typeof (object), typeof (UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object SelectedDataGridItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedDataGridItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedDataGridItemProperty, value); }
    }

    private void MyAwesomeDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedDataGridItem = MyAwesomeDataGrid.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyAwesomeDataGrid" SelectionChanged="MyAwesomeDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged"/>
</UserControl>
```

Now, this code will work:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxOnMainWindow"
             Text="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControlWithGrid,
                            Path=SelectedDataGridItem.name}"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But why I can't just access to DataGrid of UserControl but can just access to DataGrid of MainWindow? How to explain this?